# Чем являются элементы окна в Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, com

Доброго времени суток. Во всех учебных материалах(сайтах, книгах) говорится, что *все контролы, объекты взаимодействия с пользователем - это ни что иное, как обычные **Дочерние Окна***. Однако, если посмотреть на проводник(или другое Windows приложение) с помощью **spy++** , то окажется, что это утверждение неправильно. Зачастую все элементы помещены в дочерние окно с классом **DirectUiHwnd**. Неужели они являются просто графикой? Расскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Нет тут общего ответа, контролы внутри окна могут быть чем угодно. Может быть как графикой, так и окнами.

Comment: Эмм что "Да"? Да - графика?Если графика, то рисовать самому как? Создавать свои COM - объекты?

Comment: ixSci , а как по-Вашему, лучше окна, или графика?